# How to add rule in the after script for gitlab-ci.yml. after_script config should be an array containing strings and arrays of strings error

Tags: gitlab-ci

I try to create yml file where the build calls another test(project) if the build succeeds.
So I try to add a rule `when on_success` into the `after_script` block:

```yaml
before_script:
  - echo "Before script section"
  - echo "For example you might run an update here or install a build dependency"
  - echo "Or perhaps you might print out some debugging details" 

after_script:
  when: on_success
  script:
    - echo "success"

test2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Hello world"      

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Do your build here"

test1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - exit 1
```

In this result, I got the error `GitLab CI configuration is invalid: after_script config should be an array containing strings and arrays of strings`

How to implement this logic in the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

When you put `before_script:` and `after_script:` on top of the level in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, you're basically saying that all jobs (that includes `test2`, `deploy` and `test`) will run `before_script:` and `after_script:`.

> I try to create yml file where the build calls another test(project) if the build succeeds.

In this case, take a look at `allow_failure:` (see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure). By default, `allow_failure:` is already `false`. I can't really figure out from the sample `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that you shared about what you actually wanted to do, but I can give you a quick example:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo build something

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo test something

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo test something
```